# PHP shell_exec returning string with no line breaks

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am executing a shell script from PHP with shell_exec like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('./intnacstat.sh "'.$ip.'" 2>&1');
```

intnacstat.sh result is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
 description ISE dot1x Port
 switchport access vlan 70
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 70
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 256
 switchport mode trunk
 authentication event fail action next-method
 authentication host-mode multi-host
 authentication open
 authentication order dot1x mab
 authentication priority dot1x mab
 authentication port-control auto
 authentication periodic
 authentication timer reauthenticate server
 authentication timer inactivity server
 authentication violation restrict
 mab
```

---

So every command is on separate line.

But when I echo $output on PHP everything is on a single line,
basically unreadable:

"show run interface G0/8 Building configuration... Current configuration : 767 bytes ! interface GigabitEthernet0/8 description ISE dot1x Port switchport access vlan 70 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q switchport trunk native vlan 70 switchport trunk allowed vlan 256 switchport mode trunk authentication event fail action next-method authentication host-mode multi-host authentication open authentication order dot1x mab authentication priority dot1x mab authentication port-control auto authentication periodic authentication timer reauthenticate server authentication timer inactivity server authentication

Can someone tell me how to echo the $output to also add line brakes at the end of the command.
Or any other way this can be done.

Comment: `intnacstat.sh result is:` you mean results or contents ?

Comment: well if i run ./intnacstat.sh from the cli I got root@netdisco:/var/www/html# ./intnacstat.sh  10.97.31.130
show run interface G0/8
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 767 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
 description ISE dot1x Port
 switchport access vlan 70

Comment: if i do cat -E in the resutl of the intnacstat.sh root@netdisco:/var/www/html# cat -E stat.txt
$how run interface G0/8
$uilding configuration...
$
$urrent configuration : 767 bytes
$
$nterface GigabitEthernet0/8
$description ISE dot1x Port
$switchport access vlan 70
$switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q  there are no line breaks on the end of the lines. So probably the expect script in not ok.

Comment: it's hard to maintain external software like your case , but it is not the normal behavior for shell_exec , try to use exec instead and check

Answer (score 3):

I think the result is correct but rendered as `text/html` by the browser.

Add `header("Content-type: text/plain");` before printing `$output`.

Comment: Thank you mate. You are so wonderful to teach me something new!! And I am quite old programmer !

Comment: shell_exec is for executing CLI (command line console), not browser

Comment: Yes, it's executing on the server, but sending back the output. The browser thinks it's HTML and does not render line breaks. If you change the content type (using `header`) it will render as text as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Try `echo "<pre>". $output."</pre>";`

**Tip**: Use the `<pre>` tags when displaying text with unusual formatting (includes line breaks and when printing arrays using `print_r($arr)`)